Why does `datatool` fail when used in a Tikz figure
Consider the following example
\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{test.csv}
Actual,Class 1,Class 2,Class 3
Class 1,1480.0,0.0,125.0
Class 2,112.0,1303.0,180.0
Class 3,174.0,95.0,1331.0    
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb[keys={Actual,Class 1,Class 2,Class 3}]% <options>
{test}% <db name>
{test.csv}% <filename>

\newcommand{\fetchdata}[2]{\DTLfetch{test}{Actual}{Class #1}{Class #2}}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}

Hi \fetchdata{1}{1}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            colormap={bluewhite}{color=(white) rgb255=(90,96,191)},
            xlabel=Predicted,
            xlabel style={yshift=-30pt},
            ylabel=Actual,
            ylabel style={yshift=20pt},
            xticklabels={Class 1, Class 2, Class 3}, % changed
            xtick={0,...,2}, % changed
            xtick style={draw=none},
            yticklabels={Class 1, Class 2, Class 3}, % changed
            ytick={0,...,2}, % changed
            ytick style={draw=none},
            enlargelimits=false,
            colorbar,
            xticklabel style={
              rotate=00
            },
            nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta},
            nodes near coords style={
                yshift=-7pt
            },
        ]
        \addplot[
            matrix plot,
            mesh/cols=3, % changed
            point meta=explicit, draw=gray
        ] table [meta=C] {
            x y C
            0 0 0.5
            1 0 0.01809
            2 0 0.02366
            
            0 1 0.05839
            1 1 0.90109
            2 1 0.01290
            
            0 2 0.06525
            1 2 0.08082
            2 2 0.96344
        };
        
        % Add text in a specific position
        \node[anchor=south, yshift={-20pt}] at (axis cs:0,0) {(1531)};
        \node[anchor=south, yshift={-20pt}] at (axis cs:1,0) {(30)};
        \node[anchor=south, yshift={-20pt}] at (axis cs:2,0) {(33)};
        \node[anchor=south, yshift={-20pt}] at (axis cs:0,1) {(102)};
        \node[anchor=south, yshift={-20pt}] at (axis cs:1,1) {(1494)};
        \node[anchor=south, yshift={-20pt}] at (axis cs:2,1) {(18)};
        \node[anchor=south, yshift={-20pt}] at (axis cs:0,2) {(114)};
        \node[anchor=south, yshift={-20pt}] at (axis cs:1,2) {(134)};
        \node[anchor=south, yshift={-20pt}] at (axis cs:2,2) {(1344)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

This produces

However, If I try to put \DTLfetch inside the tikzpicture environment, that is:
\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{test.csv}
Actual,Class 1,Class 2,Class 3
Class 1,1480.0,0.0,125.0
Class 2,112.0,1303.0,180.0
Class 3,174.0,95.0,1331.0    
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb[keys={Actual,Class 1,Class 2,Class 3}]% <options>
{test}% <db name>
{test.csv}% <filename>

\newcommand{\fetchdata}[2]{\DTLfetch{test}{Actual}{Class #1}{Class #2}}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            colormap={bluewhite}{color=(white) rgb255=(90,96,191)},
            xlabel=Predicted,
            xlabel style={yshift=-30pt},
            ylabel=Actual,
            ylabel style={yshift=20pt},
            xticklabels={Class 1, Class 2, Class 3}, % changed
            xtick={0,...,2}, % changed
            xtick style={draw=none},
            yticklabels={Class 1, Class 2, Class 3}, % changed
            ytick={0,...,2}, % changed
            ytick style={draw=none},
            enlargelimits=false,
            colorbar,
            xticklabel style={
              rotate=00
            },
            nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta},
            nodes near coords style={
                yshift=-7pt
            },
        ]
        \addplot[
            matrix plot,
            mesh/cols=3, % changed
            point meta=explicit, draw=gray
        ] table [meta=C] {
            x y C
            0 0 0.5
            1 0 0.\fetchdata{1}{1}
            2 0 0.02366
            
            0 1 0.05839
            1 1 0.90109
            2 1 0.01290
            
            0 2 0.06525
            1 2 0.08082
            2 2 0.96344
        };
        
        % Add text in a specific position
        \node[anchor=south, yshift={-20pt}] at (axis cs:0,0) {(1531)};
        \node[anchor=south, yshift={-20pt}] at (axis cs:1,0) {(30)};
        \node[anchor=south, yshift={-20pt}] at (axis cs:2,0) {(33)};
        \node[anchor=south, yshift={-20pt}] at (axis cs:0,1) {(102)};
        \node[anchor=south, yshift={-20pt}] at (axis cs:1,1) {(1494)};
        \node[anchor=south, yshift={-20pt}] at (axis cs:2,1) {(18)};
        \node[anchor=south, yshift={-20pt}] at (axis cs:0,2) {(114)};
        \node[anchor=south, yshift={-20pt}] at (axis cs:1,2) {(134)};
        \node[anchor=south, yshift={-20pt}] at (axis cs:2,2) {(1344)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

I get
Undefined control sequence.
\edtlgetrowforvalue ...def \@dtl@dogetrowforvalueLaTeX
Undefined control sequence.
\edtlgetrowforvalue ...#3}}\@dtl@dogetrowforvalueLaTeX
Undefined control sequence.
\dtlgetentryfromrow ...3->\edef \@dtl@do@getentryLaTeX
Undefined control sequence.
\dtlgetentryfromrow ...\the #3}}\@dtl@do@getentryLaTeX
Undefined control sequence.
\DTLfetch ...olumnindex {#1}{#4}}\dtlcurrentvalueLaTeX
Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>LaTeX
Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>LaTeX
Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text>LaTeX
Undefined control sequence.
\dtlgetrowindex ...@ {#4}\edef \dtl@dogetrowindexLaTeX
Undefined control sequence.
\dtlgetrowindex ...he \toks@ }}\dtl@dogetrowindexLaTeX
Undefined control sequence.
\dtlgetrowforvalue ...lse \dtlrownum =\dtl@rowidxLaTeX
Undefined control sequence.
\dtlgetrowforvalue ...idx \relax \edef \dtldbnameLaTeX
Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>LaTeX
Undefined control sequence.
\dtlgetrowforvalue ...csname \edef \@dtl@dogetrowLaTeX
Undefined control sequence.
\dtlgetrowforvalue ... {\the \toks@ }{\dtl@rowidxLaTeX
Undefined control sequence.
\dtlgetrowforvalue ...dtl@rowidx }}\@dtl@dogetrowLaTeX
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\pgfmathresult ...romrow {\dtlcurrentvalue }{2}{}}LaTeX
Undefined control sequence.
\dtlgetrowindex ...he \toks@ }}\dtl@dogetrowindexLaTeX
Undefined control sequence.
\dtlgetrowforvalue ...lse \dtlrownum =\dtl@rowidxLaTeX
Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>LaTeX
Undefined control sequence.
\dtlgetrowforvalue ...m =\dtl@rowidx \relax \edefLaTeX
Undefined control sequence.
\dtlgetrowforvalue ...idx \relax \edef \dtldbnameLaTeX
Undefined control sequence.
\dtlgetrowforvalue ...me dtldb@#1\endcsname \edefLaTeX
Undefined control sequence.
\dtlgetrowforvalue ...csname \edef \@dtl@dogetrowLaTeX
Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>LaTeX
Missing { inserted.
<to be read again>LaTeX
Undefined control sequence.
\dtlgetrowforvalue ...dtl@rowidx }}\@dtl@dogetrowLaTeX
Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>LaTeX
Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>LaTeX
Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>LaTeX
Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...LaTeX
Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...LaTeX
Missing { inserted.
<to be read again>LaTeX
Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>LaTeX
Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>LaTeX
Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>LaTeX
Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>LaTeX
Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>LaTeX
Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>LaTeX
Extra \fi.
\CheckEncodingSubset ...:\f@family \endcsname \fiLaTeX
Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>LaTeX
Extra \else.
\CheckEncodingSubset ...dafter \@firstoftwo \elseLaTeX
Extra \fi.
<recently read> \fiLaTeX
Argument of \tc@subst has an extra }.
<inserted text>LaTeX
Paragraph ended before \tc@subst was complete.
<to be read again>LaTeX
Extra \fi.
\GenericError ...rstchoice@ \else 6\fi \endcsnameLaTeX
Extra \fi.
\?-cmd ...ndcsname {\TextSymbolUnavailable #1}\fiLaTeX
Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>LaTeX
Extra \fi.
\?-cmd ...endcsname \csname ?\string #1\endcsnameLaTeX
Extra \fi.
\?-cmd ...sname \csname ?\string #1\endcsname \fiLaTeX
Extra \else.
\?-cmd ...\string #1\expandafter \endcsname \elseLaTeX
Extra \fi.
<recently read> \endcsnameLaTeX
Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>LaTeX
Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>LaTeX
Extra \fi.
<recently read> \endcsnameLaTeX
Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>LaTeX
Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>LaTeX
Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>LaTeX
Extra \else.
\CheckEncodingSubset ...name #2:?\endcsname \elseLaTeX
Extra \fi.
\CheckEncodingSubset ...e #2:\f@family \endcsnameLaTeX
Extra \fi.
\CheckEncodingSubset ...:\f@family \endcsname \fiLaTeX
Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>LaTeX
Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>LaTeX
Extra \else.
\CheckEncodingSubset ...dafter \@firstoftwo \elseLaTeX
Extra \fi.
<recently read> \fiLaTeX
Argument of \tc@subst has an extra }.
<inserted text>LaTeX
Paragraph ended before \tc@subst was complete.
<to be read again>LaTeX
Extra \fi.
\GenericError ...rstchoice@ \else 6\fi \endcsnameLaTeX
Extra \fi.
\?-cmd ...ndcsname {\TextSymbolUnavailable #1}\fiLaTeX
Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>LaTeX
Extra \fi.
\?-cmd ...endcsname \csname ?\string #1\endcsnameLaTeX
Extra \fi.
\?-cmd ...sname \csname ?\string #1\endcsname \fiLaTeX
Extra \else.
\?-cmd ...\string #1\expandafter \endcsname \elseLaTeX
Extra \fi.
<recently read> \endcsnameLaTeX
Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>LaTeX
Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>LaTeX
Extra \fi.
<recently read> \endcsnameLaTeX
Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>LaTeX
Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>LaTeX
Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>LaTeX
Extra \else.
\CheckEncodingSubset ...name #2:?\endcsname \elseLaTeX
Extra \fi.
\CheckEncodingSubset ...e #2:\f@family \endcsnameLaTeX
Extra \fi.
\CheckEncodingSubset ...:\f@family \endcsname \fiLaTeX
Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>LaTeX
Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>LaTeX
Extra \else.
\CheckEncodingSubset ...dafter \@firstoftwo \elseLaTeX
Extra \fi.
<recently read> \fiLaTeX
Argument of \tc@subst has an extra }.
<inserted text>LaTeX
Paragraph ended before \tc@subst was complete.
<to be read again>LaTeX
Extra \fi.
\GenericError ...rstchoice@ \else 6\fi \endcsnameLaTeX
Extra \fi.
\?-cmd ...ndcsname {\TextSymbolUnavailable #1}\fiLaTeX
Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>LaTeX
Extra \fi.
\?-cmd ...endcsname \csname ?\string #1\endcsnameLaTeX
Extra \fi.
\?-cmd ...sname \csname ?\string #1\endcsname \fiLaTeX
Extra \else.
\?-cmd ...\string #1\expandafter \endcsname \elseLaTeX
Extra \fi.
<recently read> \endcsnameLaTeX
Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>LaTeX
Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>LaTeX
Extra \fi.
<recently read> \endcsnameLaTeX
Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>LaTeX
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on main.log.
Latexmk: Getting log file 'main.log'
Latexmk: Examining 'main.fls'
Latexmk: Examining 'main.log'
Latexmk: Summary of warnings from last run of *latex:LaTeX

That make not sense... Why \DTLfetch don't work as expected in `tikz picture?

Expansion issue. I have an umbrella answer at verbatim - Why can't I use  inside the argument of ? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange

In particular one of the linked questions from there is specific to DTL expansion - How to extract year from date in iso 8601 format? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange you must somehow move the fetch outside separate from the usage.

Things are not that easy with \DTLfetch because this macro is not expandable. But you can make use of the approach used in this nice answer to store the output of \DTLfetch in another macro after expasion.
Furthermore, I guess you don't want your input to be 0.1480.0, but just 0.1480, so you could create a macro that allows you to multiply the returned value with a factor. For example like this:
\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{test.csv}
Actual,Class 1,Class 2,Class 3
Class 1,1480.0,0.0,125.0
Class 2,112.0,1303.0,180.0
Class 3,174.0,95.0,1331.0    
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb[keys={Actual,Class 1,Class 2,Class 3}]% <options>
{test}% <db name>
{test.csv}% <filename>

\newcommand{\fetchdata}[4][1]{%
    \DTLfetch{test}{Actual}{Class #3}{Class #4}%
    \edtlgetrowforvalue{test}{\dtlcolumnindex{test}{Actual}}{Class #3}%
    \dtlgetentryfromcurrentrow{\dtlcurrentvalue}{\dtlcolumnindex{test}{Class #4}}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{#2}{#1*\dtlcurrentvalue}%
}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            colormap={bluewhite}{color=(white) rgb255=(90,96,191)},
            xlabel=Predicted,
            xlabel style={yshift=-30pt},
            ylabel=Actual,
            ylabel style={yshift=20pt},
            xticklabels={Class 1, Class 2, Class 3}, % changed
            xtick={0,...,2}, % changed
            xtick style={draw=none},
            yticklabels={Class 1, Class 2, Class 3}, % changed
            ytick={0,...,2}, % changed
            ytick style={draw=none},
            enlargelimits=false,
            colorbar,
            xticklabel style={
              rotate=00
            },
            nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta},
            nodes near coords style={
                yshift=-7pt
            },
        ]
        \fetchdata[0.001]{\myResult}{1}{1}
        \addplot[
            matrix plot,
            mesh/cols=3, % changed
            point meta=explicit, draw=gray
        ] table [meta=C] {
            x y C
            0 0 0.5
            1 0 \myResult
            2 0 0.02366
            
            0 1 0.05839
            1 1 0.90109
            2 1 0.01290
            
            0 2 0.06525
            1 2 0.08082
            2 2 0.96344
        };
        
        % Add text in a specific position
        \node[anchor=south, yshift={-20pt}] at (axis cs:0,0) {(1531)};
        \node[anchor=south, yshift={-20pt}] at (axis cs:1,0) {(30)};
        \node[anchor=south, yshift={-20pt}] at (axis cs:2,0) {(33)};
        \node[anchor=south, yshift={-20pt}] at (axis cs:0,1) {(102)};
        \node[anchor=south, yshift={-20pt}] at (axis cs:1,1) {(1494)};
        \node[anchor=south, yshift={-20pt}] at (axis cs:2,1) {(18)};
        \node[anchor=south, yshift={-20pt}] at (axis cs:0,2) {(114)};
        \node[anchor=south, yshift={-20pt}] at (axis cs:1,2) {(134)};
        \node[anchor=south, yshift={-20pt}] at (axis cs:2,2) {(1344)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



You can also parse the table with pgfplotstable directly, which is  a bit tricky, admittedly, because you need to rearrange the values in the table, but it works (I am unsure, however, why I obviously need to set enlargelimits={abs=0.5}, xmin=0 when replacing the inline table with a command):
\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{filecontents*}[noheader, overwrite]{test.csv}
Actual,Class 1,Class 2,Class 3
Class 1,1480.0,0.0,125.0
Class 2,112.0,1303.0,180.0
Class 3,174.0,95.0,1331.0    
\end{filecontents*}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{test.csv}\mydata
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\mydata}
\pgfmathsetmacro\mydatarows{\pgfplotsretval} 

\pgfplotsforeachungrouped \i in {1,...,\mydatarows} {
    \pgfplotstablenew[
        create on use/x/.style={
            create col/expr={\pgfplotstablerow}
        },
        create on use/y/.style={
            create col/expr={\i - 1}
        },
        create on use/C/.style={
            create col/assign/.code={
                \pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerow}{[index]\i}\of\mydata
                \pgfmathparse{\pgfplotsretval/10000}
                \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\pgfmathresult
            }
        },
        columns={x, y, C}
    ]{\mydatarows}\mytempdata
    \pgfplotstablevertcat\mynewdata\mytempdata
}

\begin{document}

% test output of table
% \pgfplotstabletypeset[]{\mynewdata}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            colormap={bluewhite}{color=(white) rgb255=(90,96,191)},
            xlabel=Predicted,
            xlabel style={yshift=-30pt},
            ylabel=Actual,
            ylabel style={yshift=20pt},
            xticklabels={Class 1, Class 2, Class 3}, % changed
            xtick={0,...,2}, % changed
            xtick style={draw=none},
            yticklabels={Class 1, Class 2, Class 3}, % changed
            ytick={0,...,2}, % changed
            ytick style={draw=none},
            enlargelimits={abs=0.5}, 
            xmin=0,
            colorbar,
            xticklabel style={
                rotate=00
            },
            nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta},
            nodes near coords style={
                yshift=-7pt
            },
        ]
        \addplot[
            matrix plot,
            mesh/cols=3, % changed
            point meta=explicit, 
            draw=gray
        ] table [meta=C] \mynewdata;
        
        % Add text in a specific position
        \node[anchor=south, yshift={-20pt}] at (axis cs:0,0) {(1531)};
        \node[anchor=south, yshift={-20pt}] at (axis cs:1,0) {(30)};
        \node[anchor=south, yshift={-20pt}] at (axis cs:2,0) {(33)};
        \node[anchor=south, yshift={-20pt}] at (axis cs:0,1) {(102)};
        \node[anchor=south, yshift={-20pt}] at (axis cs:1,1) {(1494)};
        \node[anchor=south, yshift={-20pt}] at (axis cs:2,1) {(18)};
        \node[anchor=south, yshift={-20pt}] at (axis cs:0,2) {(114)};
        \node[anchor=south, yshift={-20pt}] at (axis cs:1,2) {(134)};
        \node[anchor=south, yshift={-20pt}] at (axis cs:2,2) {(1344)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



It is incredible how LaTeX makes simple things complicated :(

Your solution really work, but the problem is that it is not scalable. If I want to fetch all data, I need to create a lot of macros. Isn't there a way to get all data systematically, no matter how large the data file is?

Hm, why do you need datatool at all then? Can't you just read in the data via PGFPlots directly?

I tried to do it in this MWE, but it didn't work out.

I added another answer that uses pgfplotstable (which loads pgfplots) direclty. Where do you get the values of the node that you place later? Can't you extract this as well from the table data?
